# How to use my own markup language for Rails model data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a blog application and I want to use my own markup language for writing posts. It's syntax is similar to Textile and Wiki. What is the simplest way to do this? Maybe there is some markup language builder gem where I can just set up the rules?

I use Rails 3 and Haml templates.

Answer (score 0):

The best method for this would be to [define your own Haml filter](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Haml/Filters.html) to transform your markup into what it should be.